# Making an array of file paths in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, filepath

This might be a stupid question, but I can't seem to find an answer. I'm pretty new to Javascript, and I want to know how to declare files/file paths as a variable, so I can put them in an array.

Like, if I have a lot of images in a folder (as in, several hundred) and I want to display certain ones based on the tags the user selects, there must be a way to have those image files in an array so a For loop can cycle through them, right?

(Even better would be if it could somehow parse an int into a filename like [i].png if I have the files named 1.png, 2.png, etc but I don't know if that's possible)

Anyway, basically all I need to know is how to make an array of files, so that "Pictures[245]" refers to "images/small/245.png"

I feel like I must be overlooking something obvious.

Comment: Can you share more details about your problem? What keeps you from putting these files into the array structure you want to use?

Answer (score 1):

There it is:

```
var Pictures = [];

Pictures.push("/images/small/0.png");
Pictures.push("/images/small/1.png");
Pictures.push("/images/small/2.png");
```

Then you can get them by calling `Pictures[0]`, `Pictures[1]`, etc.

Notice that array index starts from zero, so if you would use above solution and if you would add images in order, then your image `245.png` would be under index `244` not `245`.

If you just want to create URL to an image by file name or some identifier, then do not use array, simply use function:

```
getImageUrl(index) {
   return "/images/small/" + index + ".png";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Essentially you just want to do.

```
var picture = []; //Define array pictures

//loop through all pictures
for (i = 0; i < (amount of images); i++) {
    picture.push("/images/small/" + i + ".png"); //Add to array
}
```

Now you can call  `picture[0]` ... `picture[1]` ... etc...